# How to compile my npm lib with webpack andwhat config?

Tags: npm, webpack, package

I am making a js that I aim to publish npm. It will be used on both web and node. 
I read webpack doc and I use this following config. Bundled and minified, it produces a 20kb package, which, IMHO, is pretty big for what it does.
Should I bundle it with webpack that way ?

```
{
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        mylib: './src/mylib_browser.ts', // same for node
        "mylib.min": './src/mylib_browser.ts'
    },
    watch: true,
    target: 'web', // node for node
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name]_browser.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'MyLib',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            include: /\.min\.js$/,
        })
    ],
};
```

And I have the same config for node.

Is it the right config to do it? How could I decrease size ?
Also, when I look at other npm package, a lot are just vanilla js. Should I just let the user of my npm package, package it as a normal dependency ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the minification is happening? You have UglifyJs only minifying already minified files, which seems wrong?

```
new UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    include: /\.min\.js$/, //<= remove this line
})
```

> Also, when I look at other npm package, a lot are just vanilla js. Should I just let the user of my npm package, package it as a normal dependency ?

If your library will be packaged by consumers then I would distribute with both minified and unminified sources. This allows consumers to include the minified library via one of the npm CDNs (e.g. [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/)) when hacking around (e.g. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)) and the unminified when using the library as part of a bundled application, e.g. via webpack.

If your library is only meant for the Node environment then minification is generally considered unnecessary and even a burden should the consumer encounter a bug in your library and wish to debug it.

Comment: Minification is made by webpack when i have mode===prod. Hum. But how should i stop using webpack and juste use typescript for generating my lib? Because i have this umd settings that makes webpack add stuff.